# Python regex and spaces?

Tags: python, regex

If I have a piece of text, i.e.

`title="gun control" href="/EBchecked/topic/683775/gun-control"`

and want to create a regular expression that matches (see inside `<>` below)

`title="<1 word or many words separated by a space>" href="/EBchecked/topic/\w*/\S*"`

How do I solve that part in the `<>`?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse HTML; why not use a proper HTML parser instead? [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) makes HTML handling a breeze: `for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True): print link.attrs.get('title', 'No title set'), link['href']`.

Comment: that is a way better idea than me trying to write bad regexes... good suggestion - I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Martijn - could you help me get started using beautiful soup?  if I wanted to get all the hyperlinks from <div class="md-content-wrapper resizable-content topic-content "> of the url http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/596738/Tipperary - How would I do that exactly?  Thanks again for your previous input and 2x thanks in advance if you get around to answering this question!

Comment: You *could* make that a proper question; I'd use `content = soup.find('div', 'topic-content')`, then `for link in content.find_all('a', href=True): print link.attrs.get('title', 'No title set'), link['href']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will match 1 word or many words separated by a space:

```
\w+( \w+)*
```

Here a "word" is considered to consist of letters, digits, and underscores.  If you only want to allow letters you could use `[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*`.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @brett No problem, if my answer works you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking the outline of the check mark next to the answer.  This lets others on the site know that you found a solution.